# Function prints on Console but not Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, import

I am wanting to convert a function from one file into a GUI. I have looked up how to do it, but I just can’t find the solution. What I have now, the function prints in the console, but not on the GUI.

My code:

Function File:

```
def commentary():
    print(“Welcome to the Game”)
```

TKinter File:

```
From tkinter import *
From function import commentary

win = Tk()
open_comm = Label(win, text=commentary()).grid(row=0, column=0)
win.mainloop()
```

When I run the GUI, nothing appears on it, but the function appears in the console. How can I make the function appear in the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Function file you could return the text.

```
def commentary():
    return “Welcome to the Game”
```

This should work